# Convert JSON object to Java bean using org.json package

Tags: java, json

I have Java bean class, for example:

```
public class User  implements Serializable{
    protected String Name        = null;
    protected String Password    = null;
    // ...
}
```

I can convert it easily to `org.json` object using

```
User u = new User();
u.setName("AAA");
u.setPassword("123");
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(u);
```

Is it way to convert `JSONObject` to Java bean class?

Comment: No, Java isn't Python, you can't create classes on runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do that using the json.org library.

Depending on your needs, you can either

1. write a `fromJSONObject()` method for each of your beans, which uses `JSONObject#has()` and `JSONObject#get*()` to get the needed values and handle any type problems.
2. Write a global method which uses `JSONObject#names()` and reflection to populate a bean instance with data from a JSONObject. This is not difficult, but could be too heavy lifting if all you need it to use it with a couple of bean classes.

Answer (score 10):

There's an existing library that implements the reflection method to convert JSON Object to Java bean, called [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Using it you can convert JSON text (the result of calling `jo.toString()` in your code) back to the `User` type:

```
User user = new Gson().fromJson(jSONObjectAsString, User.class);
```

This library also implements a `toJson()` method, so it should be possible for you to replace your use of the json.org implementation with Gson for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Object toBean(JSONObject jobject, Object object) {
    for (Field field : object.getClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.set(object, jobject.getString(field.getName()));
    }
}

Call:

User user = (User) toBean(jo, new User());
```

Comment: Do you mean `object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` ? Forgot the `return` statement.

Comment: add this statement `field.setAccessible(true);`