# How to convert JSON.stringify to java object to json?

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a html table that I am converting to json format and sending to my POST type server. Given below is the ajax call to send the data to the url.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost:8090/DocVaccine",
   contentType: "application/json",
   type: 'POST',
   data: JSON.stringify(convertTableToJson()),
   success: function (data) {
       alert("DATA SENT");
   }
 });
```

On receiving the data, (which is in string format) i simply print to check its format.

```
 @RequestMapping(
        value = "/DocVaccine", 
        method=RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*/*",
        produces = "application/json", consumes="application/json")
    public void UpdateVaccineCard(@RequestBody String p1) throws IOException 
   {
        LOGGER.info(p1);
    }
```

this is the output i get. How do i convert this into java object?  I have a vaccine class which defines all the headers such as id, dueDate, dateGiven, etc. I need to convert this into proper json format to store into my mongo database.

```
 "[{\"id\":\"345678\",\"dueDate\":\"07-08-2019\",\"dateGiven\":\"07-02-2016\",\"vaccine\":\"BCG\",\"age\":\"Birth\",\"weight\":\"20\",\"heigth\":\"110\",\"placeName\":\"Hiranandani\",\"bmi\":\"0\"},
 {\"id\":\"345678\",\"dueDate\":\"08-08-2019\",\"dateGiven\":\"08-02-2016\",\"vaccine\":\"HepB\",\"age\":\"Birth\",\"weight\":\"20\",\"heigth\":\"110\",\"placeName\":\"Hiranandani\",\"bmi\":\"0\"},
 {\"id\":\"345678\",\"dueDate\":\"09-08-2019\",\"dateGiven\":\"09-02-2016\",\"vaccine\":\"Polio virus\",\"age\":\"Birth\",\"weight\":\"30\",\"heigth\":\"110\",\"placeName\":\"Hiranandani\",\"bmi\":\"0\"},
 {\"id\":\"345678\",\"dueDate\":\"10-08-2019\",\"dateGiven\":\"10-02-2016\",\"vaccine\":\"Hib\",\"age\":\"6 weeks\",\"weight\":\"30\",\"heigth\":\"110\",\"placeName\":\"Hiranandani\",\"bmi\":\"0\"},
 {\"id\":\"345678\",\"dueDate\":\"11-08-2019\",\"dateGiven\":\"11-02-2016\",\"vaccine\":\"PCV\",\"age\":\"6 weeks\",\"weight\":\"30\",\"heigth\":\"110\",\"placeName\":\"Hiranandani\",\"bmi\":\"0\"},
 {\"id\":\"345678\",\"dueDate\":\"12-08-2019\",\"dateGiven\":\"12-02-2016\",\"vaccine\":\"RV\",\"age\":\"6 weeks\",\"weight\":\"30\",\"heigth\":\"110\",\"placeName\":\"Hiranandani\",\"bmi\":\"0\"},
 {\"id\":\"345678\",\"dueDate\":\"13-08-2019\",\"dateGiven\":\"13-02-2016\",\"vaccine\":\"Typhoid\",\"age\":\"6 weeks\",\"weight\":\"30\",\"heigth\":\"110\",\"placeName\":\"Hiranandani\",\"bmi\":\"0\"},
 {\"id\":\"345678\",\"dueDate\":\"14-08-2019\",\"dateGiven\":\"14-02-216\",\"vaccine\":\"MMR\",\"age\":\"9 months\",\"weight\":\"30\",\"heigth\":\"110\",\"placeName\":\"Hiranandani\",\"bmi\":\"0\"},
 {\"id\":\"345678\",\"dueDate\":\"15-08-2019\",\"dateGiven\":\"15-02-2016\",\"vaccine\":\"Varicella\",\"age\":\"1\",\"weight\":\"30\",\"heigth\":\"110\",\"placeName\":\"Hiranandani\",\"bmi\":\"0\"},
 {\"id\":\"345678\",\"dueDate\":\"16-08-2019\",\"dateGiven\":\"16-02-2016\",\"vaccine\":\"HepA\",\"age\":\"1\",\"weight\":\"30\",\"heigth\":\"110\",\"placeName\":\"Hiranandani\",\"bmi\":\"0\"},
 {\"id\":\"345678\",\"dueDate\":\"17-08-2019\",\"dateGiven\":\"17-02-2016\",\"vaccine\":\"Tdap\",\"age\":\"7\",\"weight\":\"40\",\"heigth\":\"110\",\"placeName\":\"Hiranandani\",\"bmi\":\"0\"}}]"
```

Comment: use gson library https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON object to Java bean using org.json package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204323/convert-json-object-to-java-bean-using-org-json-package)

Comment: I found this online for the suggestion given. Now how do i convert that array i have received to single lines?

        String json = "{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Effective Java\",\"author\":\"Joshua Bloch\"}";

              Gson gson = new Gson();
             JsonElement element = gson.fromJson(json, JsonElement.class);
             JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject()

Comment: @Ele How do i separate out each line? Ive received an array in string form. How do i get each document out separately?

Comment: @KeshviSrivastava **Using JSON API:** `JSONArray array = new JSONArray(str)` and then loop using an index `JSONObject jobj = array.getJSONObject(i)`

Comment: JSONArray array = new JSONArray(str) 

This is not valid